# MVC3 ModelState fails after changing to using a ViewModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel

I've changed my controller to pass a VoucherBatchViewModel instead of a VoucherBatch

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Guid id, VoucherBatchViewModel voucherBatchViewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            SetupDropDowns();
```

And the vm:

```
 public class VoucherBatchViewModel
{
    public VoucherBatch VoucherBatchInVM { get; set; }
    public string CreationReference { get; set; }
    public int NumberToMove { get; set; }
    public int VoucherCodeLength { get; set; }
}
```

**Question:** Why is my ModelState invalid?  The drop down has not populated the correct field in the ViewModel.  The html does produce the correct

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("VoucherProviderId",
            new SelectList(ViewBag.VoucherProviders as System.Collections.IEnumerable,
            "Id", "Name", Model.VoucherBatchInVM.VoucherProviderId))
```

and Edit get contains this which I use to populate the DropDown.

```
 ViewBag.VoucherProviders = uow.VoucherProviders.OrderBy(v => v.Name).ToList();
```

Html:

```
    <select id="VoucherProviderId" name="VoucherProviderId"><option value="0469f9ba-c4ea-401a-86f1-095208c6a7fb">Name</option>
<option selected="selected" value="e0aeed44-3574-46f1-a493-0a6a87948942">Voucher Provider 1</option>
<option value="5abe1158-282b-4330-9b11-01de503a2f16">Voucher Provider 2</option>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't see any `VoucherProviderId` property in your `VoucherBatchViewModel`. So your HTML is not valid. It should be:

```
<select id="VoucherProviderId" name="VoucherBatchInVM.VoucherProviderId">
    ...
</select>
```

And to achieve this markup you I would recommend you using strongly typed helpers:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.VoucherBatchInVM.VoucherProviderId,
    new SelectList(ViewBag.VoucherProviders as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "Id", "Name")
)
```

And please replace this `ViewBag` which is making me vomit with a strongly typed model property:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.VoucherBatchInVM.VoucherProviderId,
    new SelectList(Model.VoucherProviders, "Id", "Name")
)
```

Comment: great work. I was laughing when I read your love of the ViewBag!  So I've changed it up to be strongly typed, and will be using this in the future :-)